# Connection to a Microsoft Access database using Microsoft Visual Studio?

Tags: c#

My big problem with this code is that when I try to connect to my database, the program throws a fit. I push my btnSubmit_Click button, and it tells me this error: "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine." I put my code below. Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong?

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OleDbConnection Connect;
            OleDbCommand command;
            Connect = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + @"C:\Users\drwi\Desktop\database\Javadata1.accdb");
            Connect.Open();
            command = Connect.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "insert"+txtFirstName.Text+","+txtLastName+"into T_Users;";
            Connect.Close(); 
        }

        private void Display_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OleDbConnection Connect;
            OleDbCommand command;
            Connect = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + @"C:\Users\drwi\Desktop\database\Javadata1.accdb");
            Connect.Open();
            command = Connect.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "Select * from T_Users;";
            OleDbDataReader read = command.ExecuteReader();
            if (read.Read())
            {
                txtOutput.Text = read["UserID"].ToString()+","+read["FirstName"].ToString()+","+read["LastName"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid DataBase Connection");
            };
            Connect.Close(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't use a server. The program merely needs to run based on the computer's database file.

Comment: See something odd in `txtFirstName.Text+","+txtLastName+` ? Also read up on SQL injection attacks.

Comment: You're still probably missing the MDAC install

Comment: This is indeed a duplicate, despite the fact you're not using a server. The solution is the same as given in the other post - install the proper version of MDAC on the machine where the app is to be run.

Comment: What exactly is an MDAC? I'm still in college and this is the final project I have to write for my class. We have it so it will work, we just have to make it connect to the Access Database.

Comment: Just click to the link given above and read

Comment: Run [MDAC Utility: Component Checker](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1953) on your computer and let us know which version you have installed.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

- Install [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

If you are still having issues

- Install [2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734)

Answer (score 0):

```
command.CommandText = "insert"+txtFirstName.Text+","+txtLastName+"into T_Users;";
```

should be

```
command.CommandText = "insert '" +txtFirstName.Text + "', '" + txtLastName.Text+ "' into T_Users;";
```

(add the .text)

Comment: While that is indeed going to be the *next problem* faced by this user, it's not the answer to the question asked here. (The syntax error would generate a different exception, not a "provider not registered" exception.)

Comment: @KenWhite you right, I wanted to downvote but I retain myself